# Load Word2Vec model in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, word2vec

Is it possible to load a pretrained (binary) model to spark (using scala) ? I have tried to load one of the binary models which was generated by google like this:

```
    import org.apache.spark.mllib.feature.{Word2Vec, Word2VecModel}


    val model = Word2VecModel.load(sc, "GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin")
```

but it is not able to locate the metadata directory. I also created the folder and appended the binary file there but it cannot be parsed. I did not find any wrapper for this issue.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a quick function to load in the google news pretrained model into a spark word2vec model. Enjoy.

```
def loadBin(file: String) = {
  def readUntil(inputStream: DataInputStream, term: Char, maxLength: Int = 1024 * 8): String = {
    var char: Char = inputStream.readByte().toChar
    val str = new StringBuilder
    while (!char.equals(term)) {
      str.append(char)
      assert(str.size < maxLength)
      char = inputStream.readByte().toChar
    }
    str.toString
  }
  val inputStream: DataInputStream = new DataInputStream(new GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream(file)))
  try {
    val header = readUntil(inputStream, '\n')
    val (records, dimensions) = header.split(" ") match {
      case Array(records, dimensions) => (records.toInt, dimensions.toInt)
    }
    new Word2VecModel((0 until records).toArray.map(recordIndex => {
      readUntil(inputStream, ' ') -> (0 until dimensions).map(dimensionIndex => {
        java.lang.Float.intBitsToFloat(java.lang.Integer.reverseBytes(inputStream.readInt()))
      }).toArray
    }).toMap)
  } finally {
    inputStream.close()
  }
}
```

Comment: what about fasttext? how we can load a fasttext .bin to each executor once. I tried to do that but the model is loaded per partition which isnot good when there is a high number of prtition

Comment: it sounds like you need to use broadcast... load the model once, on the driver, then distributed it via a broadcast wrapper.

Comment: @Andew Cherneski can you please my question about the same subject https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54540970/how-to-load-a-file-in-each-executor-once?noredirect=1#comment96563878_54540970

Answer (score 0):

It is an unresolved issue:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-15328

Either look at the specific code and try to recreate something for yourself or maybe use a python or C script to convert the binary to txt data and work from there.

[Convert word2vec bin file to text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27324292/convert-word2vec-bin-file-to-text/27329142#27329142)

Comment: After converting bin to text file how should I load the model?