# Loading pre-trained word embeddings

Tags: python-3.x, word2vec, spacy

I am trying to load the pre-trained word2Vec model using the command below but get an Unicode error. Need some help getting to the bottom of it. I googled around but could not find a working solution to this.

```
python -m spacy init-model en /tmp/google_news_vectors --vectors-loc ~/Downloads/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz


UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x94 in position 7: invalid start byte
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xa5 in position 0: invalid start byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22216076/unicodedecodeerror-utf8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xa5-in-position-0-invalid-s)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spacy expects the vectors to be in the text format rather than the binary format:

https://spacy.io/api/cli#init-model

For how to convert the binary model, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33183634/461847